# Are XSS attacks, or any other where a third party script is used as the attack vector, Living Off the Land (LOtL) Attacks?

Tags: xss, attacks

I'm an intern at a big company and my education is in Security Risk Analysis but I somehow got put on a software development team and am basically relegated to research. I'm surrounded by software dev's who I can't really ask for clarification on security questions so here I am.

I'm looking into using refresh tokens with PKCE on browser based-apps (which seems like a really bad idea). Anyway, one of the things I found for doing this securely was Token Binding, which Google decided not to implement citing in part a low frequency of token interception attacks, like XSS and the token leaking to third party scripts running in the browser.

However, Symantec, in their ISTR 24 document, noted the supply chain and Living Off the Land attacks increased by 78% last year. I'm trying to figure out if this is going to pose a future threat to Single Sign On and Single Page Applications due tho their vulnerability to malicious scripts. If the attacks mentioned above are LOtL attacks, then that could indicate an emergent threat, yes?

Answer (score 1):

LOtL are commonly referred to when talking about internal testing EG using available binaries on the device to run commands instead of bringing your own. As far as XSS it could be possible to load vulnerable libraries but in that case, why wouldn't an attacker write their own script considering there are no antiviruses which would detect XSS. LOtL is used where ever I see it to bypass AV by using a signed and trusted binary in a way in which it is commonly used for a malicious purpose.

Comment: This is my understanding of living off the land as well. >How scrapy are you as an attacker. Do you need your root kit, or do you know how to discover/use tools and info that are in place on the box? I'm not sure if XSS would qualify